# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API method calls metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am considering building some services using the new Web API that's introduced in ASP.NET MVC 4 (currently in beta version). I am quite clear on the way these services can be invoked using REST which returns responses either in JSON or xml.

However is there a way where I can add these services reference in client application and ***generate stubs for response objects***, similar to the way .NET response objects are created when we add a WSDL reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API does not have any such built in capability. Short of providing some WSDL-like metadata information that the existing VS tooling could read VS 2010 does not have a way to create a CLR object from a JSON service.

However, another approach you could consider is to create a simple class library with the DTO (data transfer objects) classes that could be used by both the server and the client.

Comment: thanks for the response. Are you aware of any samples on how to implement these DTO (Data Transfer Objects) classes using Web API?

Comment: just craeate a new class library project, add some model classes representing your models (perhaps with the appropriate serialization attributes so that they serialize correctly) and reference that from both the client and server.